# Pine Script bgcolor - Need continuous color until 2 conditions are met

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to shade the background green when I trigger 2 conditions (moving average slope and RSI value) for a long entry and keep it green until I trigger 2 conditions (moving average slope and RSI value) for a short entry.

The result is not keeping the desired color until the next 2 conditions are met.
The circled areas on the chart show a red background, but should be green because 2 short conditions were not met.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Image attached for reference.
[image: chart showing problem]

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Bryan Test2", overlay=true, pyramiding=5, initial_capital=10000, commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order, commission_value=4, slippage=2, calc_on_every_tick=true)
     
// STEP 1:
// Inputs in the Settng Window

MAPeriod = input.int(66, "Exponential Moving Average Period", defval=66, minval=1, group="Moving Average")
RSIPeriod = input.int(11, "RSI Period", defval=11, minval=1, group="RSI")

RSIConfirmBuy = input.int(55, "RSI Buy Value", defval=55, minval=1, group="RSI")
RSIConfirmSell = input.int(34, "RSI Sell Value", defval=34, minval=1, group="RSI")

TP1Perc = input.float(3, "Take Profit 1 (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3, group="TP & SL") 
//TP2Perc = input.float(4, "Take Profit 2 (%)",minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=4, group="TP & SL") 
SLPerc = input.float(1.5, "Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1.5, group="TP & SL")

TP1_Ratio = input.float(90, "TP 1 Postion Size %", defval=90, step=1, group="TP & SL", tooltip="Example: 50 closing 50% of the position once TP1 is reached")/100


// Calculate moving averages and RSI
maNow = ta.ema(close, MAPeriod)
maLast = ta.ema(close[1], MAPeriod)
myRSI = ta.rsi(close, RSIPeriod)


// What is the current signal?
longCondition1 = maNow > maLast
longCondition2 = myRSI >= RSIConfirmBuy
enterLong = longCondition1 and longCondition2


shortCondition1 = maNow < maLast
shortCondition2 = myRSI <= RSIConfirmSell
enterShort = shortCondition1 and shortCondition2


//Why Doesn't this work?
plotshape(enterLong, title=" Long ", style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)


exitLong = enterShort
exitShort = enterLong


// Plot moving averages
plot(maNow, linewidth=3, color=maNow > maLast ? color.new(color.green,0) : color.new(color.red, 0))


// The background should be continuous, either red or green.
// Once an enterLong condition is met, the background should be green continuously until a enterShort condition is met
// then the background should be continuous red until the next enterLong signal.
// ERROR:  There are areas of the background where longCondition1 (above) is triggered and it changes the background.
//         This should not happen.

backColor = enterLong ? color.new(color.green, 90) : color.new(color.red, 90)

bgcolor(color=backColor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the var keyword to declare the backColor variable so that you can retain it's value across bars until your conditions are met for changing the color.

```
var color backColor = na
var color green = color.new(color.green, 90)
var color red = color.new(color.red, 90)

if enterLong
    backColor := green
if enterShort
    backColor := red
```